# jQuery Load JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I've got a small dilemma, that should hopefully be easy to resolve.

I am loading some data using jQuery/JSON/PHP-- essentially, the data being loaded are several `<li>` elements.

The following code works correctly:

```
function load_list() {
$.getJSON('json/load.php', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(k, v){                                 
            $("#my_div").append('
                                         <li> \
                                          <div> \
                                           <input type="checkbox"> \
                                          </div> \
                                          <div>'+v.due_date+'</div> \
                                          <h3> \
                                           <span>'+v.title+'</span> \
                                           </h3> \
                                          </li> \
                                                  ');
                                        });
});
}
```

However, let's say I want to update `"#my_div"` and call the function again later on, say, every 20 seconds.  If I re-call the function above, it actually appends the items again, thus duplicating the results.

**My question is** (forgive me for not knowing):  How can I rewrite the function above to load all events and refresh it and set the HTML of the `"#my_div"` to be brand new and not to not duplicate?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `$("#my_div").empty()` at the beginning of the anonymous function containing the `.each()` call.

Comment: +1 - All the other answers are forgetting the fact this is in a loop :)

Comment: Hi Ignacio, thanks for the reply.  This certainly did the trick.  I can accept this as the "correct" answer in 7 minutes (according to SO).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [`html` function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set an element's HTML content, like this:

```
        $("#my_div").html('
                                     <li> \
                                      <div> \
                                       <input type="checkbox"> \
                                      </div> \
                                      <div>'+v.due_date+'</div> \
                                      <h3> \
                                       <span>'+v.title+'</span> \
                                       </h3> \
                                      </li> \
                                              ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `html` instead `append`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `html('<li>...')` tag -- it replaces content rather than appends it.

Answer (score 0):

Dodinas, you'd want to use the following:

```
$("#my_div").html('<li>...</li>');
```

using the html() method inserts the html.